# Importancia de variables con datos faltantes en R

Tags: r

Me encuentro trabajando con una base de datos (5000 observaciones) en la cual tengo una variable Y respuesta, y aproximadamente 50 variables dependientes o X (correlacionadas entre si).

Estoy interesado en encontrar las 5 variables X más importantes que defienen la variación de esa variable Y. Pero tengo registros incompletos en esas variables X (sin datos).

Qué tecnica podrían recomendarme para este objetivo (ejemplo: Random Forest no tolera faltantes). A su vez estoy interesado en trabajar con R esta técnica sugerida.

Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Primero puedes omitir los faltante na.omit(DATA)
puedes completar los datos faltante con la media o los pronostico de regresión.

```
#ejemplo completando con la media.
DATA$variable[is.na(DATA$variable)]<-mean(DATA$variable)     
#casi todas las técnicas te piden los datos completos.
```

Random Forest ??
antes de trotar debes saber caminar, primero haga un análisis exploratorio de los datos.
luego análisis de datos (usando las técnicas normales de análisis de datos, nada de random forest ni nada de eso)

De ultimo al tener claro las relaciones si puedes aplicar Random Forest y similares.

Saludos